# Android animation and layout stretch

Tags: android, animation

I have a question,
I am animating my top layout off the screen on button click, it is working as I want it to, however just under that layout I have another one, that is set to be below the top animated one.
What I would like to have is whenever my layout is animated away that space is taken by that second layout, and whenever my layout comes in, it pushes the one under.
Is it possible? If so, any tips on how would I accomplish such thing?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to use `RelativeLayout` as main layout and don't position the inner layouts . keep the order in this way:

```
1- the one to be below
2- the one to be animated.
```

In this way, the second one will always be at the top of first one unless it is animated out.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "match_parent">

<Layout 1>
<Layout 2(the animated one)>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: In case if you didn't understand]

Comment: Yes but then if the first one is not beign animated it overlays content of the second one and that I would like to somehow change

Comment: you can play with setVisibilty() attribute to set visibility of below layout to INVISIBLE when the animated one is on top